# Add the ability for moderators to undelete chat messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools

Relatively frequently, either due to mishandled flags, or due to a misclick, messages end up deleted when they shouldn't be.

This is particularly odd, since everywhere else on the network, moderators have the tools needed to correct minor mistakes like these. However, any error in chat means those messages are permanently gone.

Would it be possible to add a feature allowing for moderator undeletion of deleted chat messages?

Comment: I think this *could* be useful, but I can't think of any case where I would've needed to undelete a message. Worse comes to worse, the person will repeat themselves.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I've had it happen before where undeleting a message would have been helpful, but I'll admit it doesn't come up too often. Still, it's inconsistent behavior: undeleting a comment I deleted doesn't come up often either, but it can still be done when needed.

Comment: I agree with @Zizouz212, I'm hard pressed to find a useful application of this. A chat message really isn't that important... it might be nice to have in a very very few cases, but otherwise...

Comment: @hichris123 Same thing with undeleting comments, though. It's a low-priority feature request to be sure, but it would be nice to have.